# take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver while keeping font of html (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, fonts

I'm trying to generate images from html files which contain different fonts with Selenium WebDriver. But when I take the screenshot, the image I got always returns the same font, but not with the same font in html file. Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Example of code in python
Font in html: **Parkavenue, cursive** but the font in image we got from screenshot is **Arial**.

```
## python

html ="""
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html{background-color: white}
            table{font-family:Parkavenue, cursive, serif;text-align:center;border-collapse:inherit; border-spacing: 0}
            td,th{width: 339px; height : 50px;border:3px dotted black;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><th rowspan="2"><span id=4>shipments % S.A. sher,AD.; common </span></th>
            <th colspan=3><span id=5>% </span></th>
            <th rowspan="2"><span id=6>.KAZG.O.,,, C AND S.A. </span></th>
            </tr><tr><th colspan=0><span id=7>WARD, S.L. </span></th>
            <th colspan=0><span id=8>Gross body Buena Contains &nbsp AT &nbsp Sciences surface </span></th></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"""
driver = Firefox()

driver.get("data:text/html," + html)
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

[image_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNHlk.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-core
sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-extra
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt -f install
```

that fixed the fonts problem for me but I still can't render some fonts like hebrew so I guess this is not the perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation would be your device not having the font installed. If that is the case, WebDriver will load the page in already installed Arial.

I had a similar problem when running a Selenium WebDriver on Colab. Colab has only 1-2 fonts preinstalled, so my screenshots of websites in Unicode languages (Armenian, Georgian, Arabic namely) appeared to have squares instead of actual characters because none of the default fonts support these languages. Uninstalling them and installing a custom font (Sylfaen) with this snippet solved the issue.

```
!rm -r /usr/share/fonts/truetype/humor-sans
!rm -r /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation
!cp sylfaen.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype
!fc-cache -vf
```

In your case, try:

```
cp parkavenue_cursive_font_file /usr/share/fonts/truetype
fc-cache -vf
```

After which, install and use Selenium.